# Apache proxy with ssl not show basicauth dialog from back-end

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a Apache proxy which serve the ssl for the client. The Apache then proxy to a plain http tomcat server.

```
Listen 7777
<VirtualHost *:7777>
    ServerName my.server.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /some.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /some.pem
    SSLProxyEngine on

    # Replace HTTP response headers (http to https)
    Header edit Location ^http:(.*)$ https:$1

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://my.server.com:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://my.server.com:8888/

    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is working fine but when I access

```
https://my.server.com:7777/jmx-console
```

I get a

```
http status 403 Access to the specified resource () has been forbidden.
```

If I access the backend directly

```
http://my.server.com:8888/jmx-console
```

I get the basic authentication dialog

I want the Apache to show the backend basic authentication dialog from tomcat. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use 'proxy-chain-auth':

```
SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
AuthType basic
AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
```